# tmi.js How to check if user already ran a certain command

Tags: javascript, bots

I'm working on the twich bot and I'm trying to check if specific user already ran a command. I have this piece of code:

```
    if (message === '!iq') {
    
    var iqNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1;
    client.action('jimmytag', `${user['display-name']} Your IQ is ` + iqNum);

}
```

It just randomizes the number between 1-200. But I want it to check if user already ran it before, and print the difference. So if I type the command two times, the first time for example it will print "Your IQ is 100"; But the second time it should be "Your IQ is 150 (+50)". How can I do that?

Comment: You'll need to keep track of users who ran the request and the results they got.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty object (below const client)

```
const userIQ = {};
```

Code for the Twich chat command

```
    if (message.toLowerCase() === '!iq') {
    const hasIQ = userIQ.hasOwnProperty('userid');

    if (hasIQ == true) {

        var oldiqNum = userIQ['useriq']
        var newiqNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1;
        var iqDif = newiqNum-oldiqNum;

        userIQ.useriq = newiqNum;

        if(iqDif>0){
            client.action(channel, `@${userstate.username} Your IQ is ` + newiqNum + `(` + `+` + iqDif  + `)`);
        } else {
            client.action(channel, `@${userstate.username} Your IQ is ` + newiqNum + `(` + iqDif  + `)`);
        }

    } else {

        var iqNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200) + 1;

        var userid = userstate['user-id'];
        userIQ.userid = userid;

        userIQ.useriq = iqNum;
        client.action(channel, `@${userstate.username} Your IQ is ` + iqNum);
    }
}
```